# iOS RealmSwift DB Migration Primary Keys

Tags: ios, swift, realm, database-migration, realm-migration

I was migrating from Obj-C realm to RealmSwift. I have some changes in primary keys and data types I used following code,

```
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Countries.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                        newObject!["Country_Code"] = oldObject!["Country_Code"]
                    }
                }
```

Is there any way to dynamically migrate the properties without hard coding each property.

We have tried using nested migration.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is a little vague. Are you asking if properties can be migrated without telling Realm which old property maps to which new property? Or maybe your asking if they will migrate automatically if they have the same property name?

Comment: Don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Right. But what does *migrate entire realm classes* mean? There is no requirement to do a migration unless the class properties change in a destructive manner removed or modified. Additive changes do not require a migration. Additionally, no migration is requires to go from ObjC to Swift as the underlying data is platform agnostic. So, the question needs clarity as to specifically what's being migrated. When responding in comments, be sure to add the persons name to the response to get their attention, like @Jay

Comment: we have migrated from Obj C to swift. in obj c we made all properties as optional but in swift we have given default value (non-optional). so no we have conflict on DB. Best way to handle we have large number of classes.@Jay @Piepants

Comment: You need to post more code to clearly indicate what issue you have having. If you have to migrate then the best way is with the migration block which is what you are doing so I still don't know what it is you are asking

Comment: The question is still vague. The above comment states - *in swift we have given default value* - so how would the updated objects know what the default values are without specifying those values for the updated properties in the migration block? Remember that a migration is not needed for *new* properties, only ones you're changing or removing and the migration block is how you set up default values on specific properties. So I think the answer would be no, there is no feature as dynamic migration.

Comment: @Jay [please refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229933/realm-objective-c-to-swift-migration-dynamic-migration)

Comment: Thanks. That answer would work for a very limited use case and will crash if the optional contains nil as non-optional properties cannot be nil.