# Realm Objective-C to Swift Migration (Dynamic Migration)

Tags: swift, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

In Local Database we moved from Realm (Obj-C) to RealmSwift. After migration we have an issue in local db like all the properties were declared as Optional in Obj-C. Whereas, we used non-optional in swift db. now, we are forced to migrate entire database to new one.

we can't make manually migrate each property.
like,

```
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: User.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                        newObject!["Id"] = oldObject!["Id"]
                    }
                }
```

we need a function to do migration for each property without hardcoding. Handle respective datatypes Dynamically as required.

We are trying to make dynamic function.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. It's better to update your existing question with additional info or edits and post the answer to *that* question if you have one.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the dynamic function for realm migration,

```
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                
                for objectSchema in migration.oldSchema.objectSchema {
                    
                    for property in objectSchema.properties {
                        
                        if property.isOptional {
                            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: objectSchema.className) { oldObject, newObject in
                                if let oldValue = oldObject?[property.name] as? String {
                                    newObject![property.name] = String(oldValue)
                                }
                                
                                if let oldValue = oldObject?[property.name] as? Int {
                                    newObject![property.name] = Int(oldValue)
                                }
                                
                                if let oldValue = oldObject?[property.name] as? Bool {
                                    newObject![property.name] = Bool(oldValue)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you migrate nil values?

Comment: Nil values will remain nil or null. @Joakim Danielson

Comment: But you said the new db will hold only non-optional properties so it’s hard to understand the logic behind this code.

Comment: yes, It is.
we are migrating each property to non-optional. Using the above function.

Comment: I believe you missed the point of the question asked by @JoakimDanielson. Your current properties are optional, and could be nil. How are you migrating a nil (optional) property to a non-optional property. e.g. Non-optional properties CANNOT be nil, they must contain a value. So a nil value cannot remain nil as that will crash.

Comment: This code, while it may work has a very limited range of use - there are about a dozen different property types - what if the property is a double, or a date or a Decimal128? Expanding on that, what if it's a Realm object and not a primitive, how will that migrate?

Comment: yes. but we can handle nil and respective properties seperately. 
Also it works for wide cases. @Jay